# Il m'ignore. C'est de... l'ignorance ?

Tags: vocabulaire, substantivation

Quel est le nom associé au verbe "ignorer" dans cette acception : "il ne m'aime pas donc il m'ignore" ? Est-ce l'ignorance ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Dans cette acception du verbe « ignorer », ignorance ne va pas du tout. L'ignorance est généralement définie comme l'absence de connaissance.

Dans ce cas-ci, on parlera plutôt d'*indifférence*.

> **[INDIFFÉRENCE](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/indiff%C3%A9rence)**
>
> État de celui/ce qui est indifférent, fait d'être indifférent.
>
> **[INDIFFÉRENT](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/indiff%C3%A9rent)**
>
> Qui n'est pas concerné; qui n'est pas plus concerné par une chose que par une autre; qui est insensible, détaché.

Comment: Quand on **ignore** quelqu'un, c'est qu'il ne nous est pas **indifférent**. Il s'agit plutôt d'un conflit. Je ne suis pas sûr que cette réponse convienne dans tous les cas.

Comment: @SamuelTb: je pense que tu fais un contresens, quand on ignore quelqu'un c'est qu'on est indifférent.

Comment: @SamuelTb J'avoue qu'à première vue, *indifférence* peut sembler trompeur, mais veuillez vous référer à la définition du TLFi que je viens d'ajouter à ma réponse.

Comment: @SamuelTb : dans ce cas il s'agit plutôt en effet de **mise à l'écart**.

Answer (score 1):

In English, one can ignore or be ignored because of genuine indifference, as mentioned in the good accepted answer, but also out of total [disregard](https://www.google.com/search?q=disregard&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) (the noun).

To the extent that the same is true in French, perhaps “[un mépris [total] **de**](http://context2.reverso.net/info.php?langFrom=fr&langTo=en&q=un%20m%C3%A9pris%20total%20de&langTot=fr-en)” (but not with "pour") would have a substantive connection to the verb “ignorer” as used in its “ne mériter aucune considération/attention” sense.

Comment: I think this answer is helping. Thanks.