# Demande de nom commun : le fait d'ignorer / de ne pas tenir compte de quelque chose

Tags: choix-de-mot, québec, anglicismes

Les sens d'[ignorer](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/ignorer) relevés par le Wiktionaire sont :

> - Ne pas connaître.
> - N’avoir pas une juste idée de soi-même, de ses forces.
> - Ne pas pratiquer une chose.
> - (*Québec*) (*Anglicisme*) Ne pas tenir compte de quelque chose ; faire comme si elle n'était pas là.

C'est ce dernier sens qui m'intéresse et je recherche le nom qui pourrait correspondre à son emploi dans la phrase nominale suivante :

> Création de l’article, ajout des codes-barres inexistants et ________ des autres.

"*Ignoration*" n'existe pas et bien que j'ai remplacé dans la phrase par la formulation « *et on ignore les autres.* », je souhaiterai savoir si un nom correspondant existe.

---

<sub>Cette question n'a aucun lien avec [celle-ci](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/13472/il-mignore-cest-de-lignorance) car elle ne traite pas du même sens.</sub>

Comment: Je ne vois pas en quoi ce dernier sens est un anglicisme, et il n'est certainement pas propre au québec. Il y a d'ailleurs une référence [dans le Larousse](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/ignorer/41507)

Comment: @Bartdude J'imagine que ce sens peut avoir pour origine le [sens anglais](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ignore) et s'est propagé au Français à travers le Québec? Je n'ai fait que relever les sens depuis l'article du Wiktionaire. Si tu veux plus d'infos à propos de l'étymologie de ce sens, je pense qu'il faut faire une autre question.

Comment: Ça ne donne pas un seul mot/nom, mais peut-être en ajutant « sans » aux noms qui sont un peu prés l’antonyme de ce sens de « ignorer » pourrait capter l’idée aussi (« sans considération des autres » par exemple).

Comment: @Bartdude Effectivement, l'auteur de la page du Wiktionnaire ignore des auteurs comme Sartre ([TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/ignorer) §B.1.a). Même l'[Académie](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/ignorer) donne le sens « ne pas prendre en considération » dans son édition de 1992 (mais pas dans [celle de 1935](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie8/ignorer)). Cette idée que ce sens est un anglicisme est donc obsolète, mais encore répandue.

Comment: Pas une réponse vraiment, mais on peut aussi p-ê reformuler en disant simplement _« ...ajouts des codes-barres manquants, le cas échéant.»_. Dans le sens où on sous-entend qu'on n'intervient pas si ce n'est pas requis. Merci!

Comment: Franchement, il me semble qu'en français, on parlerait de; La création de x, l'ajout de y. Sans article, cela fait bizarre.

Comment: @Lambie Il s'agissait d'enregistrements d'actions d'un traitement automatique. Le but n'est pas de former une phrase complète mais d'avoir un historique.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

J'emploierai l'une ou l'autre de ces formules :

> - Création de l’article, ajout des codes-barres inexistants et *abandon* des autres.
> - Création de l’article, ajout des codes-barres inexistants et *délaissement* des autres.
> - Création de l’article, ajout des codes-barres inexistants et *omission* des autres.

Comment: *délaissement* a une connotation trop affective à mon goût, j'aime bien les deux autres sinon. J'attends de voir d'autres réponses ;)

Comment: @YohannV.: Effectivement, *délaissement* semble excessif.

Comment: rejet ou exclusion pourraient peut-être convenir également sans gêner la compréhension, mais n'ont pas la même signification.

Comment: *exclusion* et *omission* paraissent de bons candidats, notamment : Création de l'article, ajout des codes-barres inexistants **à** l'exclusion des autres...

Comment: @GAMPUB pourquoi le **à** ? La formulation me semble étrange...

Comment: @GAMPUB Tu t'es trompé, c'est avec **exception** qu'on utilise cette formule : *"Création de l'article, ajout des codes-barres bleus à l'exception des turquoises."*. Je suis d'accord avec Random, en utilisant *exclusion* j'aurais écrit *"Création de l'article, ajout des codes-barres inexistants __et__ exclusion des autres."* Cependant, l'idée ici est de n'effectuer aucune action, et non pas d'exclure. *omission* est effectivement intéressant, mais a été donné par Toto.

Comment: @YohannV. *à l'exception* aussi, mais [*à l'exclusion*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%A0_l%E2%80%99exclusion_de) me semblait plus proche de la demande initiale.

Comment: @GAMPUB Au temps pour moi ! Ma demande correspondait plus à mettre en avant le fait que l'*on ne s'occupe pas de* ces articles. Et donc ce serait une transformation de la phrase originale en *"Création de l’article et ajout des codes-barres à l'exception des existants."*

Comment: @YohannV. De fait, la construction avec *à* paraît plus proche de ce qui était recherché, dans l'ensemble aucune bonne nominalisation correspondant à *ignorer* ou *négliger* n'est apparue dans les réponses. *en ignorant* conviendrait aussi...

Comment: @Toto Je valide omission qui correspond à ce que je cherchais, merci.

Answer (score 3):

Il y a bien le mot **prétérition**, qui répond exactement à la définition, mais il n'est plus guère utilisé que dans un contexte juridique ou rhétorique. Mon deuxième choix serait **omission**.

Comment: Bien vu! La **prétérition** est effectivement le terme le plus convenable. Dommage que l'on ne puisse voter qu'une fois! Et, même s'il était le plus souvent employé dans d'autres contextes, celui de l'OP correspond quand même le sens A du TLF.

Answer (score 3):

On pourrait aussi remplacer par "non prise en compte"

Comment: J'ai moi-même été surpris de voir une réponse aussi tardive, surtout que ça n'est qu'une ligne, mais il faudrait je pense expliquer le downvote à ce nouvel utilisateur (1 jour ici, 2 mois sur SO)... moi-même à part la taille de la réponse je ne le compreds pas, sans apporter beaucoup de valeur elle n'est pas fausse.

Comment: Je n'ai pas downvote et je viens de voir cette réponse. Le DV peut s'expliquer par le fait qu'il ne s'agisse pas d'un nom commun, alors que c'est ce que je cherchais.

Answer (score 2):

Je pense que a phrase suivante pourrait convenir :

"Création de l’article, ajout des codes-barres inexistants et non considération des autres".

Answer (score 1):

Il y aurait aussi le mot ***[oblitération](http://www.cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/oblit%C3%A9ration)***, avec un côté pathologique : « Fermeture d’un conduit, d’une cavité par accolement de ses parois ou par la présence d’un corps étranger », mais on retiendra son sens premier s’il s’agit de *supprimer* “les autres” :

> – Action d’oblitérer, d’effacer, de supprimer quelque chose ; résultat de cette action.
>
> Le 6 août 1945, sur le navire de guerre qui le ramène de la conférence de Potsdam, le président Truman annonçait ***l’oblitération d’Hiroshima*** par une bombe atomique équivalente à vingt mille tonnes de trinitrotoluène (Goldschmidt, Avent. Atom., 1962, p.59).

Mais pourquoi pas, s’il s’agit de ne pas tenir compte “des autres” et de leur appliquer une “ignoration” :

> – Création de l’article, ajout des codes-barres inexistants et ***oubli*** des autres.

Answer (score 1):

Création de l’article, ajout des codes-barres inexistants et **occultation** des autres.

Pourrait convenir également.